# Database design for a learning management

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am working on a site where a student can see his/her scores on the quizzes, exams, homework, etc. I am stuck on how should I design the tables on the database. I have two ideas but I don't know which is the one to use.

1. Make a table for each category with a column that is a key from the subjectID.
2. Make the tables dynamically at the command of the teacher of the subject.

Now, I have problems with the two.
1. Categories may vary per subject and there may be categories that the teacher may add.
2. If I make the tables dynamically, how do I relate the table to the subject?

Answer (score 0):

With so little detail it is hard to tell.

But I would assume the following

. quizz extends handout

. exam extends handout

. homework extends handout

etc.

```
handout(id, type, fields); -- for example "final exam 2014 senior blabla".
handout_student(score, #id_student, #id_handout); -- each student returns a handout
student(id, fields);
```

n-n relationship handout to student, with a score as a relationship property.